pooled time-series regression
Suppose I am running country-level time-series regressions of stock market returns $r_{i,t}$ on some global predictor $p_{t-1}$ , where $i$ and $t$ denote a country and a month, respectively:
\begin{equation}
r_{i,t}=\alpha_i + \beta_i p_{t-1}+\epsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}
Suppose I run this for 50 countries, thus getting 50 $\beta_i$. If I then want to explain why some countries are predicted on the basis of some non-time varying country characteristic $C_{i}$ I can run this cross-country regression:
\begin{equation}
\beta_{i}=\gamma + \lambda C_{i}+\omega  
\end{equation}
For example, $C$ could be a dummy for whether a country is developed or emerging , in which case we want to understand whether $p$ predicts developed countries more than it predicts emerging.
$\lambda $ is the coefficient of interest.
Now, my question: how to best do this in one step to avoid estimating $\beta$ with error and allowing the use of time-varying $C$. One option is a pooled regression (just stacking the 50 countries and interacting with $C$):
\begin{equation}
r_{i,t}=\alpha + \beta_{1} p_{t-1} + \beta_{2} p_{t-1}\times   C_{i,t} +  \beta_{3}   C_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t} 
\end{equation}
Is this equivalent to the two-step procedure outlined above or is problematic? If problematic, why so and what would be a better alternative?
Thanks
